# Why are other people able to determine what answered the posters question?

Tags: support, site

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [Deja Dup not backing up entire system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375997/deja-dup-not-backing-up-entire-system)

I apologize if this has been asked or commented on by another thread. I do not have the time to read 25 pages of search results for fear of asking a duplicate question.

Why are other people (community, moderators, etc) granted the authority/power to decide/accept/delete what I determine was an answer to MY question?

I posted a question that received two relative responses (one a partial answer to my question, and the other a link to possible solutions).

After finding the solution to my query I responded to my own question with an 'answer' that combined the two relative responses, and a solution was found.

My answer contained the following:

1. That the app in question was simply unable to perform the task.
2. That another app must be used.
3. The specific app I found.

Shouldn't I be the one that determines what answered my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... we usually do take your word for it on a self-answer. Your answer seemed okay to me, at least before you removed most of the information from it. I've returned it to an earlier state and undeleted it.